# unexpected result when type casting the return value from pthread in C

Tags: c, types, casting, pthreads, pthread-join

I was practicing pthread in C, try to work out a function that distribute the workload as equally as possible among the threads. Each thread returns a integer representing the amount of work they were assigned.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#define THREADS 3
#define ITEMS 10

pthread_mutex_t locker = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
void* worker(void* arg){
    int id = *(int*)arg;
    int chunk = ITEMS/THREADS;
    int start = chunk * id;
    int end = id == THREADS - 1 ? ITEMS : start + chunk;
    for(int i = start; i < end; i ++){
        //do some work; 
    }
    pthread_mutex_lock(&locker);
    //do some work
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&locker);
    return end - start;  //here return type should be (void *), I casted it to (int).
}

int main(void){
    pthread_t ids[THREADS];
    int args[THREADS];
    for(int i = 0; i < THREADS; i ++){
        args[i] = i;
        pthread_create(ids + i,NULL,worker,&args[i]);
    }

    int total = 0;
    int temp;
    for(int i = 0; i < THREADS; i ++){
        pthread_join(ids[i],&temp); //param here should be (void**), I cast it to (int*)
        total = total +  temp;
        printf("Thread %d process %d items\n",i,temp);
    }

    printf("Get total items:%d\n",total);
}
```

I want to sum the return value from each thread to check if all the item has been processed. Because I am lazy and it was only a small practice, I directly cast the return value of each thread from `(void *)` to `(int)`. Then I got some output which really confusing me. It turns out I can successfully read the value from variable 'temp', but when I tried to do

```
total = total + temp;
```

the value of `total` didn't changed... 
I fixed the problem by changing the type of 'temp' from `int` to `long`, but I don't see why the number of bytes located in memory is important here.

Here is an example output

```
Thread 0 process 3 items
Thread 1 process 3 items
Thread 2 process 4 items
Get total items:4
```

PS: I do know what is the right way of doing that. 
What I do not understand is what happening when I casted a integer to a pointer and then store it at a 4-byte memory? 
Why the value can be printed out but failed at calculating with it? 
What is the reason if I use long(same size with void*) instead of int (4 bytes of memory) then everything worked fine?

Comment: this line: `int temp;` should be: `int *temp = NULL;`  and this line: `total = total +  temp;` would be better written as: `total = total +  *temp;`

Comment: this line: `int chunk = ITEMS/THREADS;` performs an integer divide.  That statement has several problems.  One glaring problem is that if `THREADS` is greater than `ITEMS`, then the result of the calculation will be 0.  Probably not what you want.

Comment: regarding: `return end - start;`  There is a better way to exit thread functions.  Suggest: `int result = end-start;  pthread_exit( (void*)&result );`

Comment: when calling: `pthread_create()`, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  I.E.  if( 0 != pthread_create(...) ) { perror( "pthread_create failed"); }

Answer (score 2):

If you're careful and use `uintptr_t` from `<stdint.h>` carefully, you can do what you want, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define THREADS 3
#define ITEMS 10

pthread_mutex_t locker = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

static void *worker(void *arg)
{
    int id = *(int *)arg;
    int chunk = ITEMS / THREADS;
    int start = chunk * id;
    int end = id == THREADS - 1 ? ITEMS : start + chunk;
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
        printf("A TID %d: s = %2d; e = %2d; i = %2d\n", id, start, end, i);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&locker);
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
        printf("B TID %d: s = %2d; e = %2d; i = %2d\n", id, start, end, i);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&locker);
    return (void *)(uintptr_t)(end - start);
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t ids[THREADS];
    int args[THREADS];
    for (int i = 0; i < THREADS; i++)
    {
        args[i] = i;
        pthread_create(ids + i, NULL, worker, &args[i]);
    }

    int total = 0;
    int temp;
    void *vp;
    for (int i = 0; i < THREADS; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(ids[i], &vp); // param here should be (void**), I cast it to (int*)
        temp = (uintptr_t)vp;
        total = total +  temp;
        printf("Thread %d process %2d items (total = %2d)\n", i, temp, total);
    }

    printf("Get total items: %d\n", total);
    return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
A TID 0: s =  0; e =  3; i =  0
A TID 1: s =  3; e =  6; i =  3
A TID 2: s =  6; e = 10; i =  6
A TID 0: s =  0; e =  3; i =  1
A TID 1: s =  3; e =  6; i =  4
A TID 2: s =  6; e = 10; i =  7
A TID 0: s =  0; e =  3; i =  2
A TID 1: s =  3; e =  6; i =  5
A TID 2: s =  6; e = 10; i =  8
B TID 0: s =  0; e =  3; i =  0
A TID 2: s =  6; e = 10; i =  9
B TID 0: s =  0; e =  3; i =  1
B TID 0: s =  0; e =  3; i =  2
B TID 1: s =  3; e =  6; i =  3
B TID 1: s =  3; e =  6; i =  4
B TID 1: s =  3; e =  6; i =  5
Thread 0 process  3 items (total =  3)
B TID 2: s =  6; e = 10; i =  6
B TID 2: s =  6; e = 10; i =  7
B TID 2: s =  6; e = 10; i =  8
B TID 2: s =  6; e = 10; i =  9
Thread 1 process  3 items (total =  6)
Thread 2 process  4 items (total = 10)
Get total items: 10
```

Note that the first set of outputs (tagged `A`) are interleaved.  The second set (tagged `B`) are serialized by the mutex.  It so happens that they are executed in sequence 0, 1, 2 in this sample output; that was the normal but not a guaranteed sequence.  The last `A` line was produced by thread 2 while thread 0 had the mutex locked.  The parent process joined thread 0 while thread 2 was still busy.

One time, when the output was piped to a logging program, I got:

```
A TID 0: s =  0; e =  3; i =  0
A TID 2: s =  6; e = 10; i =  6
A TID 1: s =  3; e =  6; i =  3
A TID 0: s =  0; e =  3; i =  1
A TID 2: s =  6; e = 10; i =  7
A TID 1: s =  3; e =  6; i =  4
A TID 0: s =  0; e =  3; i =  2
A TID 2: s =  6; e = 10; i =  8
A TID 1: s =  3; e =  6; i =  5
A TID 2: s =  6; e = 10; i =  9
B TID 0: s =  0; e =  3; i =  0
B TID 0: s =  0; e =  3; i =  1
B TID 0: s =  0; e =  3; i =  2
B TID 1: s =  3; e =  6; i =  3
B TID 1: s =  3; e =  6; i =  4
B TID 1: s =  3; e =  6; i =  5
B TID 2: s =  6; e = 10; i =  6
B TID 2: s =  6; e = 10; i =  7
B TID 2: s =  6; e = 10; i =  8
B TID 2: s =  6; e = 10; i =  9
Thread 0 process  3 items (total =  3)
Thread 1 process  3 items (total =  6)
Thread 2 process  4 items (total = 10)
Get total items: 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert a pointer to or from an integer type.  Doing so invokes undefined behavior.  You also can't freely cast a `void **` to another pointer.

To do this properly, you should dynamically allocate memory in the thread for the return value, then return a pointer to that memory.  In the main thread, you need to pass the address of a `void *` to `pthread_join`, then copy/cast that pointer.

So your thread returns it's value like this:

```
void* worker(void* arg){
    ...
    int *rval = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *rval = end - start;
    return rval;
}
```

Then you retrieve that value like this:

```
void *vtemp;
int *temp;
for(int i = 0; i < THREADS; i ++){
    pthread_join(ids[i],&vtemp);
    temp = vtemp;   // you can cast to/from a void * to another pointer without a cast
    total = total +  *temp;
    printf("Thread %d process %d items\n",i,*temp);
    free(temp);
}
```